# metatrader5 installed but won't import

Tags: visual-studio-code

`mt5` is installed in Visual Studio Code, when I try to import it, I get the error - Import "metatrader5" could not be resolved.

Can anyone please tell me where to look ?  TIA

```
Requirement already satisfied: MetaTrader5 in c:\users\eric_\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (5.0.45)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7 in c:\users\eric_\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from MetaTrader5) (1.25.1)
```

followed by error above

Comment: Depending on how you installed your packages, make sure VS Code is using the same Python environment as the one where you installed your packages. See the various answers in the linked Q&A above, as well as read the VS Code docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments